# Machine Learning - Support Vector Machines

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, data-mining

I'm looking for good resources regarding **Support Vector Machines**, or suggestions where to start learning SVM.

Already used references:

- [Stanford ML course by Andrew Ng](http://dde.binghamton.edu/kodovsky/svm/index.php?content=Material) is great place to star
- A Tutorial on Support Vector Machines for Pattern Recognition, Burges, 1998
  [SVM tutorials](http://svms.org/tutorials/)
- Neural Networks and Learning Machines, Third Edition  Learning with Kernels - SVM, A. Smola

Comment: That question is awfully general.

Comment: It is general question. I can't ask for some help from people with experience ?

Comment: You certainly can, but without giving any information of your background and specific interests, it's just not a good question (for Stack Exchange).

Comment: I will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: Note that you can still improve this question by editing it.

Answer (score 5):

There are tons of tutorials for various backgrounds. What is your background?
Here is one list of tutorials: http://www.kernel-machines.org/tutorials

Comment: Thank you! I'm CS student. I'm new to Machine Learning, and I'm interested particularly in SVM. I tried with 'Learning with Kernels' by B.Schölkopf and A.Smola but I need good resources to get right background. Thanks.

Comment: Understanding the intuition is rather easy, but you will need some linear algebra, probability and optimization background to understand how it works.

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm currently watching ML course by Andrew Ng: http://www.academicearth.org/courses/machine-learning/ and I'm looking for companion book.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Metacademy](http://metacademy.org). It is a wonderful learning guide for many topics in machine learning. Specifically, [this page](http://metacademy.org/graphs/concepts/support_vector_machine) lists various resources for learning about support vector machines.

Answer (score 3):

Some background info:
You may want to start by studying perceptrons and the learning algorithm (a building block for SVMs). It may also be useful to read up a bit on kernel methods (dealing with high dimensional data) in machine learning and Lagrange multipliers and how to apply them in different optimization tasks.

For understanding the theory: 
There is a really good [tutorial on SVMs](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67119/svmtutorial.pdf) which goes through (at least briefly) a lot of the background material and gives a good intro to SVMs.

"Pattern Recognition" by S. Theodoridis and K. Koutroumbas is a really good reference for SVMs and all of the theory behind a lot of pattern recognition related topics.

In practice:
Have a look at [LibSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) and start playing around with some datasets from [UC Irvine's machine learning data repository.](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) Play around with different kernel functions and see how the classification accuracy changes under various conditions for different datasets.

Answer (score 2):

The following book is a very good and complete source on Machine Learning:

> [Neural Networks and Learning Machines, Third Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131471392) is renowned for its thoroughness and readability. This well-organized and completely up-to-date text remains the most comprehensive treatment of neural networks from an engineering perspective. This is ideal for professional engineers and research scientists.

Comment: How can it be complete if it only covers neural networks? It seems to cover SVM, though.

Comment: @Raphael: It includes all areas one needs to know about machine learning at OP's level. I recommend you to read the book before commenting.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to listed references, I would recommend the following:

- A. Nefedov. [Support Vector Machines: A Simple Tutorial](https://svmtutorial.online), 2016
- N. Cristianini, J. Shawe-Taylor. An Introduction to Support Vector Machines and Other Kernel-based Learning Methods, Cambridge University Press, 2003
- B. Schölkopf, C.Burges, A. Smola. Advances in Kernel Methods: Support Vector Learning, MIT Press, 1999
- V. Vapnik. Statistical Learning Theory, John Wiley & Sons, 1998